# How to make a dynamically named method in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method in my class that takes a parameter that's a number. It looks something like this:

```
def with_at_least_x_posts(min_posts)
    self.where("posts_counter >= ?", min_posts)
end
```

I'd like to make a method that takes that parameter inside its name, rather than in parenthesis, so instead of calling

```
User.with_at_least_x_posts(10)
```

I can call

```
User.with_at_least_10_posts
```

This would require that method to be defined via some sort of regular expression mechanism. I know that the `find_by` method works that way (i.e. `find_by_some_column`), so it should be possible?

Could someone save me some time by telling me how to achieve that in Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1 without digging into the Rails core and finding out for myself?

Thanks!

---

Update: while waiting for an answer, I've been digging into the Rails core. Seems like they're overriding the `method_missing` method in [ActiveRecord::Base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb) and delegating the handling of custom methods to a module called [DynamicFinderMatch](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/dynamic_finder_match.rb). Interesting stuff!
Would be REALLY nice to be able to define methods in Ruby like this:

```
def /with_at_least_[0-9]+_posts/
   x = $0
end
```

but I guess that's not really possible at this point in time. Interesting stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define a call within the general Ruby method `method_missing`

```
 def with_at_least_x_posts(min_posts)
   self.where("posts_counter >= ?", min_posts)
 end

 def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
   begin
     if sym.to_s =~ /with_at_least_(\d+)_posts/
       return send :with_at_least_x_posts, *(args.push($1.to_i)), &block
     end
   rescue NoMethodError => e
     raise "Unable to find method: #{e.inspect}"
   end

   return super
 end
```

From here, you'll be able to call `myObj.with_at_least_10_posts`.  Give it a go!  You can read more [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/02/ruby-replace-methodmissing-with-dynamic.html).

P.S.  This is common in Ruby (it's what ActiveRecord does).  Beware that if you get a StackOverflow error, it's because a `method_missing` error raised in `method_missing` will lead to an infinate recursion.  Be cautious!

Comment: Yeup! This is indeed the correct answer to my question, and I'm going to choose it as such. However, after the discussing between you and @Peter, I've decided that in this case it adds an unnecessary layer of complexity. I'll just go with a named scope. Thanks!

Comment: I think that's the right move in this instance.  Good to know this approach for times when it is a practical solution though.

Comment: shouldn't you call super if the regex doesn't match?

Comment: That's a good point.  I also added a begin/catch block to help secure against potential annoying Stack-Overflow issues (no pun intended...)

Comment: Shweet deal. I'd +2 it but I can't :P

Comment: Indeed, `method_missing` is the way to go, but I'm not convinced about the `rescue`; if there's an exception raised, it should not be caught. Another point: why the `self.` and why the `send`? Just call it directly. Finally, the `return super(sym, *args, &block)` is can simply be written as `super`.

Comment: I fixed the two issues you discussed, thanks!  The rescue block to prevent stackoverflow errors that tend to come up with you have an issue within method_missing (e.g. if with_at_least_x_posts happens to be undefined).  That said, I changed it to just re-raise a separate error in this case.  Does that seems fair?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `method_missing`, but this is a dangerous method that can lead to very messy code. Instead, how about

```
User.with_more_posts_than(10)
```

which is much cleaner (and much easier to work with and maintain). It still reads correctly.

As one specific point among many objections, you shouldn't convert `10` to a string and back. This brings in a huge new class of potential errors which you will later have to deal with.

Comment: I agree it's not the cleanest / clearest code structure, but it appears a *very* common practice in the Rails community.  Should we really discourage the practice wholesale?

Comment: You could think about `method_missing` as creating a whole lot of new methods. So `find_by_name` is one of these methods. But there's only a fairly small number of `find_by_xxx` methods compared to `with_at_least_1_posts`, `with_at_least_2_posts`, .... Obviously it is handled dynamically, but it's very messy.

Comment: Okay, I agree.  This case is arbitrary / unnecessary.  That said, it may be a dumbed-down version of a larger issue OP is dealing with.

Comment: Okay, in the end, I agree with both of you and have decided to create a scope with a lambda as such `scope :with_more_posts_than, lambda { |minimum_posts| joins(:users).group("posts.user_id").having("count(posts.id) > ?", minimum_posts) }`. However, this is failing and I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method empty? for 9:Fixnum` when I try to run in with any number (in this case `9`). Any ideas?

Comment: To answer my own question, for `where`, I can do something like this: `where("foo = ?", "bar")`. I can also write it as such: `where(["foo = ?", "bar"])` (note the square brackets). `having` is unable to take parameters that way, and requires the latter way. Wrapping the parameters in square brackets solves my problem: `scope :with_more_posts_than, lambda { |minimum_posts| joins(:users).group("posts.user_id").having(["count(posts.id) > ?", minimum_posts]) }`